# Azure AD B2C - Configure PasswordReset policy directly into the Custom Policy for Sign-Up/Sign-in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

In Azure AD B2C when a user clicks the "Forgot/Reset" Password, B2C redirects the user back to the Relying Party (web app), with the following error:

```
AADB2C90118: The user has forgotten their password.
Correlation ID: 124dd908-e181-408f-a363-ecbd46aa9d8e
```

The Web App (RP), should read the error code and react by redirecting the user back to B2C specifying the `PasswordReset` policy to be used. This is by design and it's documented in the official AAD B2C docs.

In our case, we have many web apps sharing the same Custom Policy (SUSI and PasswordResest), to offer a common login experience.

I would like to pick/configure the PasswordReset policy directly into our Custom Policy for sign-in. I'd like to avoid the user getting redirected back to the applications and then the apps deciding what PasswordReset Policy to use.

Is this possible to achieve in B2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from March 2021, the "Self Service Password Reset" is the recommended option. The previous method described in my original post is not considered legacy.

**Self Service Password Reset Official Documentation:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Essentially, what I asked above not only is possible now, but **it's also the recommended approach**.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not. The only proper way to handle is doing it via the application, as you already described and also according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

However, depending on your implementation and overall landscape of your identity setup, you may try using a "trick" - create a custom UI HTML template which will include an URL to the password reset policy of your choosing (static URL in the template) and hide (or disable if you use custom policies) the original "Forgot passoword" link which returns back to the app to handle. Attach that template to the policy - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

This might not work or be suitable for every setup though. You may get an unexpected behaviour in the app if you open a policy and then the flow ends in a different one. I myself consider that a rather bad practice and discourage people from using it where I work. But if you really need to have something like that you may consider it.

Comment: Yes I read this in another post (a guy has done it), but I was looking for a more "legit" way, something configurable directly into the custom policy and part of the UserJourney...

Comment: +1 for taking the time and sharing your thoughts :). Let's hope someone from AAD B2C team sees this and gives us an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is [possible](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset).

"By default when you create a sign-up or sign-in policy (with local accounts), you see a Forgot password? link on the first page of the experience. Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset policy. Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your app. Your app needs to handle this error code by invoking a specific password reset policy.

This policy demonstrates how to embed the password reset flow a part of the sign-up or sign-in policy. So, Azure AD B2C will not return the AADB2C90118 error message".

Comment: they made it the recommended approach now, released in March.